# Remapping 'Value' to its 'Key' not working in solidity?

Tags: mapping, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm learning mapping in solidity.
I have mapped 'Key'(uint) to its 'Value'(string) but unable to do it reverse i.e. mapping 'Value'(string) to its 'Key'(uint). Please help...

Note: My code compiles without any error in Remix IDE

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

pragma solidity >=0.7.1;

contract mappingInSolidity2 {
    mapping(uint => string) public sentances;
    mapping(string => uint) public indexes;
    
    function setSentance(uint _index, string memory _sentance) public {
        sentances[_index] = _sentance;
        indexes[_sentance] = _index;
    }
}
```

[Screenshot After Deploying this contract using RemixIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOCmu.png)